# Get and use a password with special characters in Bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quoting

I'm getting some troubles to use a password with special characters such as $ in a **bash** shell script.

My shell script is :

```
read -s -p "Password : " bindDNPass
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w $bindDNPass -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

And the password could be something like $Something18$.

Well, the command

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -W -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif`
```

asks for my `$Something18$`, and works fine.

But if I try

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w $Something18$ -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

it doesn't work. I guess it's trying to resolve the variable `$Something18,` so I tried with `\$Something18$`, `\$Something18\$,` `\\\$Something18$`, ... but it keeps on failing...

How can I do? (Without changing my password...)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, is it your script that fails and you want to get working, or your manual statement, or both?

Comment: Well... Finally, this solution works, but didn't solve my problem. I mean, to allow a password in linux with special characters, it works. But if you're using OpenDJ, it doesn't. I finally installed OpenLDAP and everything is fine now. I don't know what they did with the ldaputilities implementation to make it fail with such a password :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two potential problems with how you're reading and using the password:

- When you use the `read` command *without* the `-r` option, it'll try to interpret escape (backslash) sequences, which may cause trouble.
- When you use a variable *without* wrapping it in double-quotes, it'll try to split the value into separate words and also try to expand any wildcards into a list of matching filenames. This can cause *massive* confusion, so you should almost always double-quote variable references.

Fixing these potential problems gives this script snippet:

```
read -rs -p "Password : " bindDNPass
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w "$bindDNPass" -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

...But, while you should do both of these mods to make your script more robust, neither of these will change how it handles the password `$Something18$`. In fact, when I tried your original snippet with that password, it got passed to `ldapadd` correctly. If your actual password has some other special characters in it (or you've played with the value of `IFS`), these might help; otherwise, there's something else going on.

If your password still doesn't work after these fixes, try putting `set -x` before the `ldapadd` command (and `set +x` after) so it'll print what's actually being passed to `ldapadd`. Well, it'll print it in a possibly confusing form: it'll print *an equivalent command* to what's actually being executed, which means it'll add quotes and/or escapes to the password parameter as necessary so that you could run that command and it'll do the same thing. When I tried it with `$Something18$`, it printed:

```
+ ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w '$Something18$' -D dn=cn=Admin -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

...where the single-quotes mean that what's inside them is passed directly, with no parsing. It could also have printed any of the following equivalent commands:

```
+ ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w \$Something18\$ -D dn=cn=Admin -f /tmp/file.ldif
+ ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w "\$Something18\$" -D dn=cn=Admin -f /tmp/file.ldif
+ ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w $'$Something18$' -D dn=cn=Admin -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

so you have to take what it prints, and figure out how that'd be parsed by bash, in order to figure out what's actually being passed to `ldapadd`. But at least it'll give you some information about what's actually happening.

Oh, and you may notice that the DN argument isn't being double-quoted. That's because it doesn't contain any special characters, so the double-quotes aren't doing anything, so it just left them off.

Answer (score 7):

Put it in double-quotes and escape the `$` symbol avoid special interpretation from the `shell`,

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w "\$Something18\$" -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

(or) [*more recommended*]

Enclose it within single-quote to let the shell treat it as a literal string without expanding it,

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost -x -w '$Something18$' -D "dn=cn=Admin" -f /tmp/file.ldif
```

From the `man bash` page,

> *Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes*, with the **exception of $, , \, and, when
>     history expansion is enabled, !.  The
>     characters $  and retain their special meaning within double quotes**. The **backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \, or .** A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ! appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ! is not removed.

Comment: Single quotes would be preferable, since it doesn't require escaping the `$` separately. Escaping the final `$` is optional, since there is no following character to trigger a parameter expansion.